# Meaning of если что

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

I found these two recently in different sources:

> Она уже не маленькая, если что.

(talking about their daughter, who wanted to move to America)

> Я пойду и побью его. 
>   - Он 5 лет занимался боксом, если что.

The only reference I found for если что was with случится, i.e. if anything happens. What is the speaker trying to say in these examples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first can be translated as:

> She's not a kid (anymore), just in case you forgot.

or depending on the context:

> She's not a kid, (she'll be able to solve her problems) if anything happens.

The second is:

> He has five years of boxing experience, just in case you didn't know.

Or maybe "if you know what I mean" would better translate "если что" here.

The usage is slightly non-standard, but understandable.

Comment: Thank you! When you say non-standard, you mean most people wouldn't use it?

Comment: I think the standard way is using "между прочим" instead. Some people may use even "на минуточку", which is also non-standard, but widely used in colloquial speech: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_7741.

Comment: Got it! (1) "She's not a child, you know"; and (2) "He's been boxing for five years, mind you." Thanks again for your wonderful explanations :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a turn of speech combining the meanings of "if something (unclear, misunderstood, happens, goes wrong, etc)". Russians love to use vague phrases like this with different meanings. See also: [Ну ты заходи, если что](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)

Comment: On the other hand, it seems to be not done to just say "Это зовисит."

Comment: @Raskolnikov, please, check the spelling of words, before you write it on educational site like this one. I'm talking about the work "зовисит", which is normally written as "зависит".

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, *если что* has strong negative connotations or implications, such as **if worse comes to worst,** **in case of emergency/emergencies.**

*Она уже не маленькая, если что* can be rendered as *Она уже взрослая и самостоятельная, сдюжит, пройдёт все испытания и риски.*

*Я пойду и побью его. - Он 5 лет занимался боксом, если что* can be rendered as [...] ***Только ты учти:*** он 5 лет занимался боксом. Так что непростая у тебя будет задачка/ **But take note**... The speaker is implying that chances are that it's his friend, not his rival, who will be beaten.